# How to get the current logged in Windows User from MSBuild

Tags: .net, msbuild

How can we get the current logged-in windows user from Msbuild?
Is there a similar way to get it, just as we can do with Nant with the `environment::get-user-name()` function?

Answer (score 13):

You [can use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) `$(USERNAME)` to read the `USERNAME` environmental variable.

Comment: To get the username of the person who requested the build you can use the $(RequestedFor) build property - http://www.woodwardweb.com/vsts/30_useful_team.html

Comment: What if you're using NTLM and Username is blank?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is probably to use the environment variables

```
%UserName%
%UserDomain%
```

Just open a command window and type `set` to see what's defined. In MSBuild, these would be defined as $(USERNAME) and $(USERDOMAIN) - see MSDN, [How To Use an Environment Variables in a Build](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171459%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Try out this

```
<Message Text="$(USERNAME)"/>
```